# How to download in an zip archive a maven artifact (pom and jar) and all its dependencies (poms and jars too) using only a web browser?

Tags: maven, offline, nexus

I have installed an Nexus repository which is completely offline (no link to internet). Sometimes, I need to add others maven artifacts and I have only a web browser to download them, artifact by artifact, for example from http://mvnrepository.com. It is tedious... And I have no way to install a Maven client on the session running this web browser.

I am searching an online service allowing to define only the artifact to download and to get an zip file including the specified artifact and all its dependencies (POMs and jars).

http://jar-download.com/online-maven-download-tool.php is doing something like this. The user specify a dependency, eg

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and the site generates a POM, executes the maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies goal against the generated POM, and allow to download a zip file.

But this zip file does not include the POMs, only the jars, even if pom is added to the dependency tag.

I will ask the owner of this site if he can activate the copyPom parameter but maybe another online service is already doing this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: By using Nexus you can use the procurement feature which allows you exactly to control what has been cleared for your organization..etc..Unfortunately you need to buy the commercial version of Nexus...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I only use Nexus OSS. I read fast the procurement feature documentation and I feel that the repository must use an internet active connection. My Nexus repository is completely offline and I sometimes want add some artifacts from Central, which I download by hand using a web browser, transfer with an USB key to the Nexus offline repository storage area. The maven-dependency-plugin:copy-dependencies goal should allow to get the components more easily but I can't run it on my online session, on which I have only a web browser.

Comment: Manually Downloading is too time consuming and with procurment you can exactly control what is cleared and what not...By using maven-dependency-plugin you need to have a internet connection as well...so i don't see the advantage of that approache...

Comment: Yes, it is time consuming. But due to the IT policy in my organization, I am only allowed to use a Citrix session with a web browser to access the internet :-(. An applet at http://jar-download.com/online-maven-download-tool.php run the maven dependency plugin but with the default options which download only a jar artifact and all its jar dependencies, but not the POMs. I didn't found this kind of service on mvnrepository or on sonatype central, on which I can only download artifact one by one.

Comment: You can download an artifact manually from Maven Central...if you like for example you can [search for an artifact](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22junit%22%20AND%20a%3A%22junit%22) and can click on the page on the jar file?...

Comment: Thanks for this link, but it allows to download artifacts one by one which is time-consuming. I would like to specify a GAV coordinate and download all dependencies in a few clicks.